# How to apply Gradients on Label in NativeScript

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to apply gradients on Label tag but end up like this  Failed to apply property [color] with value?, I'm wondering if it's supported in NS or not if yes then how can i? my current version is 6+

Comment: Can you post some code? Are you testing on iOS?

Comment: Yes I'm testing on iOS, it's just a simple label with class of logo and logo has color property with linear-gradient.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue on iOS, followup the [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/5942) for updates.

Meanwhile wrap the label with layout, apply the gradient on layout as a workaround.